# Seaborn Barplot - Inconsistence when displaying values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For a multi-group bar plot in Seaborn, I would like to add text which is reffered from the `int_txt` on top each of the bar plot.
However, the text is not placed as intended.

For example, the code below

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# Create an example dataframe
data = {'pdvalue': [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8],
        'xval': [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 1, 1.1, 3, 1],
        'int_txt': [11, 14, 4, 5.1, 1, 2, 5.1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 6, 2, 3],
        'group': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['int_txt'] = df['int_txt'].round(0).astype(int)
df=df.sort_values(by='pdvalue', ascending=True)
g = sns.barplot (data=df,x="pdvalue",y="xval",hue="group",)

for idx,p in enumerate(g.patches):
    if p.get_height()!=0:
        val_me=df['int_txt'][idx]
        g.annotate(format(val_me, '.1f'),
                       (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                       ha = 'center', va = 'center',
                       xytext = (0, 9),
                       textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.show()
```

will produced

[image]

Whereas, the expected output shall be something like

[image]

The appended text is based on the look-up table

[image]

and for any `xval` equal to zero, no text will be appended.

May I know where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong really. It's just `sns` plots the bars by `hue` first. To see this do:

```
for idx,p in enumerate(g.patches):
    # annotate the enumeration
    g.annotate(format(idx, '.1f'),
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center',
                   xytext = (0, 9),
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
```

And you see (notice the enumeration on top)

[image]

One way around is to sort your data by `hue` column, then access with `.iloc`:

```
# sort by group first
df=df.sort_values(by=['group','pdvalue'], ascending=True)

g = sns.barplot (data=df,x="pdvalue",y="xval",hue="group",)
for idx,p in enumerate(g.patches):
    if p.get_height()!=0:
        # access with `iloc`, not `loc`
        val_me=df['int_txt'].iloc[idx]
        g.annotate(format(val_me, '.1f'),
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center',
                   xytext = (0, 9),
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
```

And you would get the expected annotation:

[image]